# tab css click to open and to close with just css

Tags: html, css

I don't want javascript.

I need when i click on the tab to open and when i click again it will close without javascript just with css please

```css
.tabordion {
  color: #333;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 85%;
}
.tabordion input[name="sections"] {
  position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
}

.tabordion section {
  display: block;
}

.tabordion input[name=sections]:checked~article {
        text-align: center;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 0px !important;
}
.tabordion section label {
        line-height: 1.1;
        display: inline-block;
    padding: 21px 0px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #2b6a83;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -2px 0 0 transparent inset;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99999 !important;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.tabordion section article {
    display: none;
    left: 0px;
    min-width: 300px;
    padding: 30px 30px 20px 21px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}

.tabordion section article:after {
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  left:-229px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 220px;
}
.tabordion input[name=sections] {
    position: absolute;
    display: none 
} label:before,input[name=sections]:checked + label {
    background-color: #f3cb5d;
    color: white;
   font-weight: 800;
}
.tabordion input[name="sections"]:checked ~ article {
  display: block;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
.ime{
    width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 170px;;
    padding: 20px
}
```

```html
<div class="tabordion"><section id="section1"><input id="option1" checked="checked" name="sections" type="radio" /><label for="option1">Family Caregivers <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</label> <article>
<div class="rom">
<div class="col-md-8 sec">
<h3>Caregiving Strategies Handbook</h3>
</div>
</div>
</article></section><section id="section2"><input id="option2" name="sections" type="radio" /><label for="option2">Alzheimer’s &amp; Dementia <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></label><article>
<h2>Alzheimer’s &amp; Dementia</h2>
<div class="rom">
<div class="col-md-4 ime"><img class="resim alignnone wp-image-21936" src="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Screen-Shot-2021-04-06-at-10.26.30-PM.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="col-md-8 sec">
<h3>Caring for Someone with Alzheimer's or Dementia</h3>
<h4>A HANDBOOK FOR CARE</h4>
<div id="btn"><span class="noselect"><a href="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Caring-for-Someone-with-Alzheimers-or-Dementia.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Read More..</a></span></div>
</div>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="rom">
<div class="col-md-4 ime"><img class="resim alignnone wp-image-21938" src="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Screen-Shot-2021-04-06-at-10.29.23-PM.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="col-md-8 sec">
<h3>Dementia: A Guide for Caregivers</h3>
<h4>Communicating about dementia with healthcare providers</h4>
<div id="btn"><span class="noselect"><a href="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Dementia-A-Guide-for-Caregivers.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Read More..</a></span></div>
</div>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="rom">
<div class="col-md-4 ime"><img class="resim alignnone wp-image-21940" src="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Screen-Shot-2021-04-06-at-10.32.29-PM.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="col-md-8 sec">
<h3>Dementia in Canada Statistics</h3>
<h4>Demintia in Canada, including Alzheimer's disease</h4>
<div id="btn"><span class="noselect"><a href="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Dementia-in-Canada-Statistics.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Read More..</a></span></div>
</div>
</div>
</article></section><section id="section3"><input id="option3" name="sections" type="radio" /><label for="option3">COPD <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></label><article>
<h2>Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (COPD)</h2>
<div class="rom">
<div class="col-md-4 ime"><img class="resim alignnone wp-image-22431" src="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/image.jpeg" alt="" /></div>
<div class="col-md-8 sec">
<h3>COPD Handbook</h3>
<h4>Signs and Symptoms of Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease</h4>
<div id="btn"><span class="noselect"><a href="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/COPD-Handbook.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Read More..</a></span></div>
</div>
</div>
</article></section><section id="section4"><input id="option4" name="sections" type="radio" /><label for="option4">Stroke <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></label><article>
<h2>Stroke</h2>
<div class="rom">
<div class="col-md-4 ime"><img class="resim alignnone wp-image-21961" src="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/iStock-1168179082.jpg" alt="" /></div>
<div class="col-md-8 sec">
<h3>A Guide for Stroke Survivors and Families</h3>
<h4>A GUIDE FOR STROKE SURVIVORS, FAMILIES, &amp; CAREGIVERS</h4>
<div id="btn"><span class="noselect"><a href="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/A-Guide-for-Stroke-Survivors-and-Families.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Read More..</a></span></div>
</div>
</div>
</article></section><section id="section5"><input id="option5" name="sections" type="radio" /><label for="option5">Palliative Care <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></label><article>
<h2>Palliative Care</h2>
<div class="rom">
<div class="col-md-4 ime"><img class="resim alignnone wp-image-21961" src="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Screen-Shot-2021-04-06-at-11.12.32-PM.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="col-md-8 sec">
<h3>A Caregiver's Guide to the Dying Process</h3>
<h4>“Dying is not primarily a medical condition, but a personally experienced, lived condition.”</h4>
<div id="btn"><span class="noselect"><a href="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/A-Caregivers-Guide-to-the-Dying-Process.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Read More..</a></span></div>
</div>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="rom">
<div class="col-md-4 ime"><img class="resim alignnone size-full wp-image-21963" src="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Screen-Shot-2021-04-06-at-11.15.12-PM.png" alt="" width="755" height="467" /></div>
<div class="col-md-8 sec">
<h3>Guiding Family Caregivers through End of Life Care</h3>
<h4>Why Do Family Caregivers Needs To Be Guided To Take Care Of Themselves?</h4>
<div id="btn"><span class="noselect"><a href="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Guiding-Family-Caregivers-through-End-of-Life-Care.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Read More..</a></span></div>
</div>
</div>
</article></section><section id="section6"><input id="option6" name="sections" type="radio" /><label for="option6">Respite Care <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></label><article>
<h2>Respite Care</h2>
<div class="rom">
<div class="col-md-4 ime"><img class="resim alignnone wp-image-21967" src="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Screen-Shot-2021-04-06-at-11.22.29-PM.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="col-md-8 sec">
<h3>Respite Care Guide</h3>
<h4>Finding What’s Best for You. Respite refers to a short time of rest or relief.</h4>
<div id="btn"><span class="noselect"><a href="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Respite-Care-Guide.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Read More..</a></span></div>
</div>
</div>
</article></section><section id="section7"><input id="option7" name="sections" type="radio" /><label for="option7">Postpartum Care <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></label><article>
<h2>Postpartum Care</h2>
<div class="rom">
<div class="col-md-4 ime"><img class="resim alignnone wp-image-21970" src="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Screen-Shot-2021-04-06-at-11.28.19-PM.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="col-md-8 sec">
<h3>Your Guide to Postpartum Care</h3>
<h4>The first 6 weeks after birth is known as the postpartum period.</h4>
<div id="btn"><span class="noselect"><a href="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Your-Guide-to-Postpartum-Care.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Read More..</a></span></div>
</div>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="rom">
<div class="col-md-4 ime"><img class="resim alignnone wp-image-21973" src="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Screen-Shot-2021-04-06-at-11.33.15-PM.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="col-md-8 sec">
<h3>Postpartum Care in Canada</h3>
<h4>The postpartum period is a significant time for the mother, baby, partner, and family.</h4>
<div id="btn"><span class="noselect"><a href="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Postpartum-Care-in-Canada.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Read More..</a></span></div>
</div>
</div>
</article></section><section id="section8"><input id="option8" name="sections" type="radio" /><label for="option8">Hospital Discharge Guide <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></label><article>
<h2>Hospital Discharge</h2>
<div class="rom">
<div class="col-md-4 ime"><img class="resim alignnone wp-image-18146" src="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/bh-blog-hospital-discharge-planning.jpg" alt="hospital discharge planning" /></div>
<div class="col-md-8 sec">
<h3>Hospital Discharge Guid</h3>
<h4>In the Hospital: Planning for Discharge, Know Who Is on the Discharge Team</h4>
<div id="btn"><span class="noselect"><a href="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Hospital_to_Home-1.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Read More..</a></span></div>
</div>
</div>
</article></section></div>
```

Comment: Could you make a small example - see [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the HTML tag 'details':

[w3schools - details](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_details.asp)

This is basically an HTML only accordion tag...

Answer (score 1):

You will surely need Javascript to do this. Or you can use Bootstrap if you want to get rid of Javascript or not to involve in JS.

In simple: You can also use Checkboxes instead of a radio button.

In your case, When you click on another tab, the previously opened tab becomes closed.

But in this case, Your previous tab will keep open until you again click on particular tab